# why my vercel dashboard is showing Build error occurred?

Tags: tailwind-css, vercel

> Build error occurred
> YAMLException: can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key at line 7, column 1:

```
^
at generateError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:167:10)
at throwError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:173:9)
at readBlockMapping (/vercel/path0/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1073:9)
at composeNode (/vercel/path0/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1359:12)
at readDocument (/vercel/path0/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1525:3)
at loadDocuments (/vercel/path0/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1588:5)
at load (/vercel/path0/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1614:19)
at Object.safeLoad (/vercel/path0/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/loader.js:1637:10)
at module.exports (/vercel/path0/node_modules/gray-matter/lib/parse.js:12:17)
at parseMatter (/vercel/path0/node_modules/gray-matter/index.js:109:17) {
```

type: 'YAMLException',
reason: 'can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key',
mark: {
name: null,
buffer: '\n' +
"title: Why Don't I Have My AI on Snapchat?\n" +
"date: '2023-07-27'\n" +
"tags: ['Developer']\n" +
'draft: false\n' +
"summary: 'Why Don't I Have My AI on Snapchat?'\n" +
'\x00',
position: 143,
line: 6,
column: 0
}
}
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

the post it deleted and its getting some error when im posting a new article form my vs code but the vercel error shows me this whole error code